# How to set the values of array to a number if it satisfies a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a matrix A size of `2x4x3x3`, where 2 means combined of two matrices `A1` and `A2`. For each matrix `A1/A2` (size of `4x3x3`), I only select the values that bigger than `0.3` (smaller than `0.3` called **uncertainty position**)  and perform `argmax` to obtain a matrix `C`. In the matrix C, I will set the value at the **uncertainty position** to 255. I have done it by two ways in python as bellow. I am looking for the third way that shorter to set the value at the **uncertainty position** to 255. Could we have it? Thanks

The code is

```
import numpy as np
A1=np.array([[[0.4,0.2,0.3],
            [0.4,0.5,0.6],
            [0.7,0.8,0.2]],
            [[0.4,0.5,.3],
            [0.2,0.5,0.2],
            [0.3,0.2,0.1]],
            [[0.5,0.1,0.6],
            [0.8,0.1,0.5],
            [0.5,0.1,0.4]],
            [[0.6,0.1,0.1],
            [0.2,0.1,0.9],
            [0.9,0.1,0.1]]])
A2=np.array([[[0.8,0.1,0.6],
            [0.4,0.6,0.6],
            [0.7,0.8,0.2]],
            [[0.4,0.8,.3],
            [0.2,0.8,0.2],
            [0.3,0.0,0.1]],
            [[0.5,0.1,0.6],
            [0.8,0.0,0.5],
            [0.5,0.1,0.4]],
            [[0.6,0.1,0.1],
            [0.2,0.1,0.1],
            [0.9,0.1,0.1]]])

A1= np.expand_dims(A1,0)
A2= np.expand_dims(A2,0)
A= np.concatenate([A1,A2],axis=0)  
B = A< 0.3

#First way
C=np.argmax(A, axis=1)
C[B[:,0,:,:]]=255
C[B[:,1,:,:]]=255
C[B[:,2,:,:]]=255
C[B[:,3,:,:]]=255
print (C)

#Second way
C=np.argmax(A, axis=1)
for i in range (4):
    C[B[:,i,:,:]] = 255
print (C)

#Third way
C=np.argmax(A, axis=1)
C[B[:,0:3,:,:]]=255
print (C)
```

You also can run it [Online Code](https://repl.it/repls/SufficientSeashellEllipse)

Comment: What do you mean by *shorter*? Do you want your code to be one liner? Or do you want it to work faster? Did you notice that your third solution does not work?

Comment: Shorter mean without loop. I tried `C[B]=255` but it was wrong

Comment: Because size of C is smaller (one dim lesser) than B. C is the result of argmax remember

Comment: How about your solution? I just used the second solution but it used loop. Can we ignore loop using vectorize?

Comment: Up. Please help!